# Statistical significance between explanatory variables

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic

Let's suppose I have this data:

$\mathbf{x}_1 = (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)^{\mathbf{T}}$
$\mathbf{x}_2 = (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)^{\mathbf{T}}$
$\mathbf{y} = (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)^{\mathbf{T}}$

I am conducting a logistic regression to find $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$ in $\mathbf{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1\mathbf{x}_1 + \beta_2\mathbf{x}_2$.

Is there a simple way to test the hypothesis $H_0: \beta_1 = \beta_2$ vs. $H_A: \beta_1  > \beta_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your linear predictor $\eta(x_1,x_2)=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2$ as $\eta(x_1, X_2)=\beta_0+\beta(x_1+x_2)+(\beta_2-\beta) x_2$. In this model you test the null hypothesis $H_0\colon \beta_2-\beta=0$ versus the alternative $\beta_2-\beta <0$.

In practice, I would do that fitting the full model and making a confidence interval based on profile likelihood for $\beta_2-\beta$.